# How to pass string from text file to another template file using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Let say I have text file contains the following strings.

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

How do I pass all those data to another template file contains the following ..

```
UserCreate 'string here' /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet 'string here' /ALIAS:none
```

So at the end it will produce output like this

```
UserCreate user1 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user1 /ALIAS:none
UserCreate user2 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user2 /ALIAS:none
.....................
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy:

```
# create the template as Here-String
$template = @"
UserCreate {0} /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet {0} /ALIAS:none
"@

# read the text file as string array
Get-Content -Path 'D:\TheUsersFile.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $template -f $_
}
```

Output:

```
UserCreate user1 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user1 /ALIAS:none
UserCreate user2 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user2 /ALIAS:none
UserCreate user3 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user3 /ALIAS:none
UserCreate user4 /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
UserNTLMSet user4 /ALIAS:none
```

The `-f` Format operator replaces all numbered placeholders in a string like `{0}` with the value(s) on the right-hand side.
You can have more than one placehlder of course. For instance

```
"This {0} gets filled in with your name: {1}" -f 'string', $env:USERNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
foreach ($user in (Get-Content -Path C:\TEMP\users.txt)){
    UserCreate 'string here' /GROUP:none /REALNAME:none /NOTE:none
    UserNTLMSet 'string here' /ALIAS:none
}
```